# Ubuntu 16.04 is slow on a 1.6 GHz -32 bit, 2GB RAM computer. What can be done?

Tags: 16.04, usb, 32-bit

**Ubuntu 16.04 is slow on a 1.6 GHz-32 bit, 2GB RAM computer. What can be done?**

I put on a 16 GB USB Stick the [32-bit PC (i386) desktop image of Ubuntu 16.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/), using Rufus.
I set my 1.6 Ghz -32 bit, 2GB RAM laptop to boot from the USB stick, started it and after about 3 minutes I had a working Ubuntu on my computer (I have not installed it yet on the HDD).

Unfortunately, this Ubuntu 16.04 is terrible slow even for basic tasks like a single window opened, more precisely "Search Your Computer", where I write the word "terminal". The next letter appears at about 0.5 seconds after the previous one. So, it will take about 4 seconds just to write the word "terminal".

Now, with Firefox opened, I can write this question faster than 0.5sec/letter but the editor is still 4-5 letters behind. This is, it continues to print the last 4-5 letters after the moment I finish writing the sentence.
Also, no matter what window I try to open, and even if the USB stick shows no activity, the reaction of Ubuntu is slow. For example, I have to wait like 0.5 seconds if I click on the upper right button that displays the list of Wi-Fi networks.

QUESTION: Is it a fix for this or simply Ubuntu 16.04 requires a computer much more powerful than mine to run smoothly?

Note:
I mention that the laptop runs Windows 7, 32 bit and it works smoothly.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu (instead of running it off the USB drive) will probably speed things up. With 2GB of RAM, it's possible that something like [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.me) would be a bit easier on system's resources than regular Ubuntu.

Comment: It's Unity's 3D effects that's slowing everything down. Install XFCE, and everything will be much better.